# How to select the item that has the greatest value in dataframe ? In Pyspark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to select the item that has the greatest value. For exemple in this table I would like to select **MAC09**

| Identifiant | Val |
| --- | --- |
| MAC26 | 36 |
| MAC10 | 9 |
| MAC02 | 2 |
| MAC32 | 11 |
| MAC09 | 37 |
| MAC28 | 10 |

Comment: The code in Pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several way of doing it, here is a solution using a rank

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window


df.withColumn("rnk", F.rank().over(Window.orderBy(F.col("Val").desc()))).where(
    "rnk = 1"
).drop("rnk").show()
+-----------+---+                                                               
|Identifiant|Val|
+-----------+---+
|      MAC09| 37|
+-----------+---+
```