# pyspark get latest non-null element of every column in one row

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let me explain my question using an example:
I have a dataframe:

```
pd_1 = pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,2,3,2,1,3], 
                     'code': [10, 10, 20,20,30,30],
                     'A': [44, 55, 66,77,88,99],
                     'B':['a',None,'c',None,'d', None],
                     'C':[None,None,'12',None,None, None]
                    })
df_1 = sc.createDataFrame(pd_1)
df_1.show()
```

Output:

```text
+---+----+---+----+----+
|day|code|  A|   B|   C|
+---+----+---+----+----+
|  1|  10| 44|   a|null|
|  2|  10| 55|null|null|
|  3|  20| 66|   c|  12|
|  2|  20| 77|null|null|
|  1|  30| 88|   d|null|
|  3|  30| 99|null|null|
+---+----+---+----+----+
```

What I want to achieve is a new dataframe, each row corresponds to a `code`, and for each column I want to have the most recent non-null value (with highest `day`).

In pandas, I can simply do

```
pd_2 = pd_1.sort_values('day', ascending=True).groupby('code').last()
pd_2.reset_index()
```

to get

```text
    code    day A   B   C
0   10       2  55  a   None
1   20       3  66  c   12
2   30       3  99  d   None
```

My question is, how can I do it in pyspark (preferably version < 3)?

---

**What I have tried so far is:**

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('code').orderBy(F.desc('day')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

## Update: after applying @Steven's idea to remove for loop:
df_1 = df_1 .select([F.collect_list(x).over(w).getItem(0).alias(x) for x in df_.columns])

##for x in df_1.columns:
##    df_1 = df_1.withColumn(x, F.collect_list(x).over(w).getItem(0))

df_1 = df_1.distinct()
df_1.show()
```

Output

```
+---+----+---+---+----+
|day|code|  A|  B|   C|
+---+----+---+---+----+
|  2|  10| 55|  a|null|
|  3|  30| 99|  d|null|
|  3|  20| 66|  c|  12|
+---+----+---+---+----+
```

Which I'm not very happy with, especially due to the `for loop`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the item that has the greatest value in dataframe ? In Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69389248/how-to-select-the-item-that-has-the-greatest-value-in-dataframe-in-pyspark)

Comment: @Steven thank you. But I think it would have the same issue of looping over all columns :|

Comment: if your issue is just the for loop, change it to list comprehension within a select

Comment: that's a good idea to improve the code :)

Comment: the problem is that each final row would consist of elements from different rows (with the same code), and not just selecting one row. I think it cannot be done using single `row_number` function. but if I miss anything please let me know or write an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your current solution is quite nice. If you want another solution, you can try using `first`/`last` window functions :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy("code").orderBy(F.col("day").desc())


df2 = (
    df.select(
        "day",
        "code",
        F.row_number().over(w).alias("rwnb"),
        *(
            F.first(F.col(col), ignorenulls=True)
            .over(w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))
            .alias(col)
            for col in ("A", "B", "C")
        ),
    )
    .where("rwnb = 1")
    .drop("rwnb")
)
```

and the result :

```
df2.show()

+---+----+---+---+----+
|day|code|  A|  B|   C|
+---+----+---+---+----+
|  2|  10| 55|  a|null|
|  3|  30| 99|  d|null|
|  3|  20| 66|  c|  12|
+---+----+---+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing by using array functions and struct ordering instead of Window:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

other_cols = ["day", "A", "B", "C"]

df_1 = df_1.groupBy("code").agg(
    F.collect_list(F.struct(*other_cols)).alias("values")
).selectExpr(
    "code",
    *[f"array_max(filter(values, x-> x.{c} is not null))['{c}'] as {c}" for c in other_cols]
)

df_1.show()
#+----+---+---+---+----+
#|code|day|  A|  B|   C|
#+----+---+---+---+----+
#|  10|  2| 55|  a|null|
#|  30|  3| 99|  d|null|
#|  20|  3| 66|  c|  12|
#+----+---+---+---+----+
```